# Quartz Scheduler With Apache.Commons.Daemon

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, apache-commons-daemon

I created a java application that uses Quartz Scheduler.
I am trying to wrap it in a Windows Service using Apache.Commons.Daemon.
The Daemon requires a start and stop method.  The start method should not complete until the stop method is called.  If I use the start method to call the Quartz Scheduler, the start method completes and control is passed to a method in the Quartz library.

The scheduler needs to be flexible (certain days of the week, and certain times of the day) but I am not tied to Quartz.
I need to be able to run the application, even if there is no user logged in, but I am not tied to Apache.Commons.Daemon.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to handle this?

Thanks,
Raymond

Answer (score 0):

I have found that srvany works well to host a java service.  No worries, srvany works on all versions of windows although the claim is smaller.  There is no stop, start.  See https://www.iceflatline.com/2015/12/run-a-windows-application-as-a-service-with-srvany/ for a short tutorial and links to the software.